# VMWare Player - Unable to share folder. (Host-Win8, Guest-Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, vmware-player, shared-folders

VM shared folder settings:

[image]
What all I have tried:

- Reinstalling VMware tools.
- Uninstall, install VMware tools.
- Turned Windows Firewall off.
- Edit out `/etc/fstab` to include the following:

  `.host:/Desktop /mnt/hgfs vmhgfs defaults,ttl=5,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0`
- Edit out `/etc/rc.local` to include:

  `mount.vboxsf -w Desktop /mnt/hgfs`

None of these work. My `/mnt/hgfs` is still empty.

Any solutions for me?

Answer (score 0):

Install samba on ubuntu guest.  You can go either way with samba.  Sharing with windows requires setting up a share in /etc/samba/smb.conf

Samba can mount a Windows share also.  The ubuntu system will require username/password for the share on the windows server.

smbmount //servername/sharename /mountdirectory -o username=mywindowsusername,password=mywindowspassword